# Point feature symbol not showing in ArcGIS Online but renders fine in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: point, arcgis-online, rendering

I've published a map layer of point features with several basic symbols for unique values. One layer that I published a couple years ago is displaying correctly, but a new layer that's almost the same will not render the point symbols, though it will display the labels and the data in a popup. I've created a test map to illustrate: https://arcg.is/1qzqSX I don't have any field names that start with numbers.

Comment: It doesn't have the values "Installed" etc... in the gauge op status field, it has numbers (3, 6) . It probably has a coded value domain.

Comment: That makes sense, but the older feature class doesn't use a domain, and this one doesn't have one defined on it. I'm just setting the symbology by unique values, where I create the text labels corresponding to the numbers. It displays fine in Arc Pro. When I publish that to AGOL, the symbols now disappear for the new feature class.  I'll try defining a domain and see if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I've created a domain for those values and you can see them in the AGOL feature table now. But it still won't display the point symbols. ?!?

Comment: No idea. If I define the symbology in AGOL map viewer, the layer displays point symbols. It's not your original symbology though.

Comment: Found it. Somehow my feature class symbology had become invalid in Arc Pro, while still displaying correctly. I just had to reselect the intended unique values field in the symbology panel, and Arc Pro was happy. I could republish and it's fixed. Thanks to your comment, I've also created a coded value domain for that field that simplifies the UX.

Comment: Excellent. You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow my feature class symbology had become invalid in Arc Pro, while still displaying correctly. I just had to reselect the intended unique values field in the symbology panel, and Arc Pro was happy. I could republish to AGOL and it's fixed.